# ng-model from radio button is always undifined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When I am fire ng-click event, ng-model is always undefined. I want to get the selected value.
The alias name works well.

```
<div ng-if="post.direction != 'digital_in' && post.direction != 'digital_out'">
    <label><input data-ng-model="dir" type="radio" name="direction" value="digital_in">digital input</label>
    <label><input data-ng-model="dir" type="radio" name="direction" value="digital_out">digital output</label>
    {{dir}}
 </div>

<td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="updatePin(post, alias, direction.value())"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></td>
```

This it the controller:

```
$scope.updatePin = function(post, alias, dir){
    console.log(post.id);

    post.alias = "" + alias;
    post.direction = "" + dir;
    $http.post('http://localhost:9000/activePinsUpdate?id=' + post.id , post).success(function(data, status) {
        $scope.loadData();
    });
};
```

Comment: Can you share your code on jsfiddle

Comment: "ng-model direction" => no, it's `ng-model dir` . use `updatePin(post, alias, dir)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may Need to Share Your Code in a Fiddle thats a Good and Quick way to Get Help ..

> Suggestion :- You may Need to use Pre-Angular Binded UI - Angular ui
>   http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/versioned-docs/0.12.0/#/getting_started
>   If you are a Starter Try to Start with the Above Links Because these
>   are Already Binded with angularjs. so You will not Face Above Kind of
>   Problems.
>
> You are Using Pure Html to Bind with angular Which Creates Chaos . Finally Understands for angular UI.

Solution :- 
Missing thing is **ng-value** .

```
<div ng-if="post.direction != 'digital_in' && post.direction != 'digital_out'">
    <label><input data-ng-model="dir" type="radio" name="direction" ng-value="digital_in" ng-checked='true'>digital input</label>
    <label><input data-ng-model="dir" type="radio" name="direction" ng-value="digital_out">digital output</label>
    {{dir}}
 </div>
```

if it is Still Not working

Pre-define `$scope.dir='digital_in';  // it updates on selecting radio.`

```
$scope.updatePin = function(post, alias, dir){
    console.log(post.id);
    post.alias = "" + alias;
    post.direction = "" + $scope.dir;   //value Updates on Check 

    $http.post('http://localhost:9000/activePinsUpdate?id=' + post.id , post).success(function(data, status) {
        $scope.loadData();
    });
};
```

Good Luck !!

Answer (score 1):

use **[`ngValue`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue)** with ng-model as object property

Like this

```
<div ng-if="post.direction != 'digital_in' && post.direction != 'digital_out'">
    <label><input data-ng-model="post.dir" type="radio" name="direction" ng-value="digital_in">digital input</label>
    <label><input data-ng-model="post.dir" type="radio" name="direction" ng-value="digital_out">digital output</label>
    {{dir}}
 </div>
```

you can access this in your ctrl like this

```
post.alias = "" + alias;
post.direction = "" + post.dir;
```

Comment: this problem  is not related to `ng-value`, basically its related to scope inheritance. for more detail look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35371114/2435473)

Comment: @PankajParkar bro i have updated my answer. I posted anwer when op provided only html . May be later he added js code that i missed. Thanks for pointing :)

Comment: technically html code is `error` prone/ title were more informative , there is nothing to do with js, though I removed downvote..

Answer (score 1):

`ng-if` directive does create a  child scope which is prototypically inherited from parent scope.

> ### On contrast Prototypal Inheritance means?
>
> If you have scope hierarchy, then parent scope property are accessible
>   inside child scope, only if those property are object (originally
>   object referenced is passed to child scope without creating its new
>   reference). But primitive datatypes are not accessible inside child
>   scope and if you looked at your code addCustom scope variable is of
>   primitive dataType.

Problem is `dir` variable with radio `ng-model` which you are using inside `ng-if` is of primitive data-type. So when `ng-if` renders `div` it does create a child scope there which has again have `dir` value. So controller `dir` variable is different than `ng-if`'s radio button `dir` scope variable.

For solving the issue you need to change from

```
data-ng-model="dir"
```

to

```
data-ng-model="post.dir"
```

So that Prototypal inheritance rule will get followed using `DOT rule`.

And from post object only you can get the value `post.dir` button, no need to pass it explicit value of `dir` then. I'm not going to explain what exactly happening behind the scene, as you can refer [this similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35371114/2435473) here which has other way to get this thing done.