# ng-repeat radio filter not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, radio-button, angularjs-filter

I am using angularJS to filter my data, the filter options are radio buttons fetched from a JSON API, but it does not work though using the usual route. my [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/dC0khQqiiP1Di49TAbar?p=preview)

**HTML**

```
<div class="category">
  <div ng-repeat="category in categories">
    <input type="radio" name="typefilter" id="{{category.title}}" ng-model="typefilter" value='{{category.title}}'>
    <label for="{{category.title}}">{{category.title}}</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="food" ng-repeat="food in foods | filter:typefilter">
  <h4>{{food.name}}</h4>
  <p ng-repeat="food in food.type">{{food}}</p>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
app.factory('Categories', ['$resource',
function ($resource) {
    return $resource('https://safe-depths-4702.herokuapp.com/api/categories/:categoryId', {
      categoryId: '@_id'
    }, {
      update: {
        method: 'PUT'
      }
    });
  }
]).factory('Foods', ['$resource',
  function ($resource) {
    return $resource('https://safe-depths-4702.herokuapp.com/api/foods/:foodId', {
      foodId: '@_id'
    }, {
      update: {
        method: 'PUT'
      }
    });
  }
]).controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,Categories,Foods) {
  $scope.categories = Categories.query();
  $scope.foods = Foods.query();
});
```

my [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/dC0khQqiiP1Di49TAbar?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whole problem boils down to you are breaking the all important rule of *always always always* use an object in `ng-model`

`ng-repeat` creates a child scope and the typefilter is a primitive only being set in each child scope. The parent scope can't see that primitive

In controller set an object:

```
 $scope.filter={}
```

In view use `filter.typefilter`

```
<div class="category">
      <div ng-repeat="category in categories">
        <input type="radio" name="typefilter" id="{{category.title}}" ng-model="filter.typefilter" value='{{category.title}}'>
        <label for="{{category.title}}">{{category.title}}</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="food" ng-repeat="food in foods | filter:filter.typefilter">
      <h4>{{food.name}}</h4>
      <p ng-repeat="food in food.type">{{food}}</p>
    </div>
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/S20PYx3IiTvqz2BD0ZSa?p=preview)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

When `ng-repeat` does render a template, it create a child scope which does prototypically inherited from parent case. And Prototypal Inheritance work on `reference` type of variable's, not on primitive type variable. In your case you are using `primitive` type variable, so it didn't get followed in your case.

Here in this case `typefilter` is scope present inside `ng-repeat`, so then `typefilter` is available inside the `ng-repeat` scope only. You can not get its value outside `ng-repeat` div. So in that case you need to explicitly point out to the parent scope using `$parent.` before `ng-repeat`'s primitive type variable.

```
ng-model="$parent.typefilter"
```

[**Working Plunkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/dC0khQqiiP1Di49TAbar?p=preview)

But this isn't a good approach to follow, as it gets tightly couple with parent controller scope(Would not work, if you are using Ionic, as it does create child scope on each `ion-content`)

Rather you should follow, either one of below approach.

1. Dot rule while defining model(already covered in @charlietfl answer)
2. `controllerAs` approach

In [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35371114/2435473), you could find the other way to solve this issue.

Comment: thank you, your solution works on plunker, but did not work on my ionic application. i could use this for browser based applications. thank you

Comment: @RohitKumarVinay yes.. for `ionic` it wouldn't work, because for each `ion-content` it creates a child scope. So i'd suggest follow `charlietfl` way.. thats why I said in my answer that.. its not correct approach to go for it.. Its kind of explanation, do refer mine reference answer. in that I covered whole points