# ng-click doesn't work in ng-repeat inside scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

I try to create a list of books which may or may not contain comments.
So I'd like to have ability to click on comments link (if it contains comments) and to see a list of comments.

I've read that each `<li>` creates its own scope. So I've tried to create local variable and show/hide comments list depending on click of "comments" link.

For some reason ng-click doesn't work and doesn't change "showComments" variables

I wrote small example to describe problem.

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

```js
 var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('bookCtrl', function($scope) {

   $scope.books=[
    {Name:"Book1",Comments:["first comment book1,second comment book1"]},
    {Name:"Book2",Comments:["first comment book2,second comment book2"]},
    {Name:"Book3",Comments:[]}
   ];
});
```

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

ul{
  list-style-type:none;
}

a:hover {
 cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-controller="booksCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="book in books">
      <div class="row">
        {{book.Name}}
      </div>
      <div>
        <a ng-if="book.Comments.length>0" ng-click="showComments = !showComments ">Comments</a>
      </div>
      <div ng-show="showComments">
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="comment in book.Comments">
            {{comment}}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: code editor needs ui-bootstrap so here it doesn't work,but this is not related to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

showComment inside `ng-repeat` is different than the outer `showComment` variable. Because `ng-repeat` does create a child scope on each iteration, while rendering a DOM. That scope is always prototypically inherited from it parent scope. You could read about [**Prototypal inheritance in this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs).

Do have `showComment` property on each, as it will also make more sense to view individual book comment

**Markup**

```
<div ng-controller="booksCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="book in books">
      <div class="row">
        {{book.Name}}
      </div>
      <div>
        <a ng-if="book.Comments.length>0" ng-click="book.showComments= !book.showComments">
           Comments
        </a>
      </div>
      <div ng-show="book.showComments">
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="comment in book.Comments">
            {{comment}}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Similar [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35371114/2435473)

Comment: Great!It works perfectly now!I should read about prototypal inheritance a little bit more.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: @VolodymyrBabak do accept answer. and read up on another linked answer.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to toggle comments per book however. So you could do this..

**Controller**

```
app.controller('bookCtrl', function($scope) {

   $scope.books=[
    {Name:"Book1",Comments:["first comment book1,second comment book1"], showComments: false},
    {Name:"Book2",Comments:["first comment book2,second comment book2"], showComments: false},
    {Name:"Book3",Comments:[], showComments: false}
   ];
```

**Html**

```
<a ng-if="book.Comments.length" ng-click="book.showComments= !book.showComments ">Comments</a>
..
<div ng-show="book.showComments">
   <ul>
       <li ng-repeat="comment in book.Comments">
          {{comment}}
       </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: *It appears that you haven't initialized the scope variable yet* it would not work after intialization due to scoping issue..

Comment: It would work but not for the purpose they were trying to achieve which is why I supplied the alternative approach.

Comment: "You will probably want to toggle comments per book however."

Comment: could you remove 1st half of your answer, which is purely wrong.. if you do that so I can remove downvote..

Comment: I understand your opinion but I believe my answer was sufficient. The first half of the answer is in response to "For some reason ng-click doesn't work and doesn't change "showComments" variables".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107995/discussion-between-pankaj-parkar-and-fintan-kearney).