# mouse leave not working properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a scenario where when i mouse enter on some text i need to get an input box and text should hide and when i leave the text box the box should hide and i should show the text back

but this is not happening

Html

```
<div ng-app>
<div ng-controller="showCrtl">
   <div ng-hide="showme">
     <p ng-mouseenter="showme=!showme">
       mouse enter
     </p> 
   </div>
   <input type="search" ng-if="showme" ng-mouseleave="showme=false">
 </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function showCrtl($scope){
  $scope.showme=false;
}
```

Here is what i have tried [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8Yz7S/220/)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: please check this fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/dMTc2/17/

Comment: Could you please specify where i am going wrong @CemArguvanlı

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you had primitive value on `ng-if` directive, You know `ng-if` does create child scope whenever it renders that element on DOM. To resolve this issue what I'd suggest you to do is, just follow `Dot Rule` by defining new object. And then define all the property which you want to use inside that object.

If you want do dig deeper how scope inheritance work, you can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35371114/2435473).

So in your code, you should define an object suppose i.e. `$scope.model = {}` and then have `showme` property inside that object itself. And wherever you use `showme` on view replace that with `model.showme`.

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ee5LcLar/)

---

More convenient way to resolve such kind of scope inheritance issue is, you could use `controllerAs` pattern. In that you don't use `$scope` inside controller, you just place with controller context `this`. While using controller on view you need to create it alias and when you want to get variable value you can use variable reference.

Comment: @Shikhathakur Glad to help you, look at the updated answer, would help you more to clear understandings. Read referred answer as well, Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you have multiple nested scopes. The `showme` that is being set in the input box is different from the `showme` being set in the `p`. This happens because Angular implicitly adds a new scope for many built-in directives (ng-if is one of them).

You need to be sure that you are always setting and reading the same `showme` property. The easiest way to do this is to add the `showme` property to the controller.

Try this:

```
<div ng-app>
   <div ng-controller="showCrtl">
     <div ng-hide="showCrtl.showme">
       <p ng-mouseenter="showCrtl.showme=!showCrtl.showme">
         mouse enter
       </p> 
     </div>
     <input type="search" ng-if="showCrtl.showme" ng-mouseleave="showCrtl.showme=false">
   </div>
</div>
```

In fact, as a general rule of thumb, never access the scope directly in your templates since it is very difficult to be sure you are accessing the scope that you think you are accessing. Always access properties through the controller you are working with.